# MVC Routing in Umbraco instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco7

I wonder if someone could help me please....

I've created a very basic ActionResult in a controller (controller called CPDPlanSurfaceController)

```
    public ActionResult removeObjective(int planId)
    {
        return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
```

and I'd like to create a URL that maps to this ActionResult (obviously there'll be more in there than just this redirect). I can't use the @Url.Action text as this doesn't seem to work in Umbraco (The url always being empty). And another problem seems to be that there isn't a routeconfig.cs in my app_start folder. So I really don't know where to start.

Ultimately I would like to end up with a URL of www.mysite.com/mypage/removeObjective/5 but I've no clue as to where to even begin to create this 'route'.

Could anyone spare me five mins to point me in the right direction.

thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you started. I might have a couple of errors here, but it should be close. I'm usually able to do

```
@Html.Action("removeObjective", "CPDPlanSurface", new RouteValueDictionary{ {"planId", 123} })
```

OR

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Me!", "removeObjective", "CPDPlanSurface", new RouteValueDictionary{ {"planId", 123} })
```

My SurfaceController usually looks like this:

```
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;
public class CPDPlanSurfaceController : SurfaceController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult removeObjective(int planId)
    {
        return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
}
```

The path to the surface controller ends up being something like:

```
/umbraco/Surface/CPDPlanSurface/removeObjective?planId=123
```

I believe if you want to do your own custom routing, you will need to do something like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CPDPlanRoutes",
            url: "mypage/{action}/{planId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "CPDPlanSurface", action = "Index", planId = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

And then on ApplicationStarted:

```
public class StartUpHandlers : ApplicationEventHandler
{
    protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to get to the method on your controller like this:

```
@Url.Action("removeObjective", "CPDPlanSurface")
```

Comment: Superb thanks matey. Turns out I was over-thinking it and your advice pointed me in the right direction. I ended up using

`@Html.ActionLink("Delete Objective", "removeObjective", "CPDPlanSurface", new { @planid = item.PlanID, @userName = Session["username"], @redirectID = 3660 }, null)`

Obviously I'd made some changes (more parameters) to the ActionResult in the controller.

Cheers bud